# Kids not even exploring other tabs/section

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, usability-testing

My app for Kids (4-10 yr).  90% kids only using video tab. Kids not even exploring  Audio & Activity section/tabs.

Actually audio & activity section is very customer engaging, attractive & interesting. But kids not exploring. I want ‘ kids minimum explorer the other section.

[image]

Comment: what is your question? This seems like the result of your user testing (actually real world usage). Is there more revenue by having kids use the Audio and Activity. It seems like so far, your user base has spoken.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the visual design.
Kids are extremely visual so its not suprising they rather check the videos which are big and flashy instead of clicking boring bottons.

Add some animations to the buttons like a little "shake" from time to time and test again, i bet more kids would klick.

Comment: I want kids open audio & activity tab. But kids do not click on audio/activity tab. I tried different color/attractive tab but not working.

Comment: what if you switched the order of the tabs in a user test? and have the default to 'activities'? If they don't spend any time on it then, your hypothesis that activities are engaging and attractive for your audience may be wrong.

Comment: 4-10 is also a huge age range. Very important cognitive changes happen in that range. You should look more closely at the different ages to see how they are interacting with it.

Comment: That's an odd position for those "tabs." The real visual design might be doing a better job of communicating that those are links to other sections of the site, but based on the wireframe it may be that you have a case of banner blindness, or that users otherwise aren't noticing that those buttons even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and user testing in this field recently.

#### Here's what I concluded:

- Children are not afraid to scroll
- You can't make them do what you want
- They don't read content
- They scan for familiar words, such as games, videos etc. **Icons
  help - A LOT!**

When it comes to the web (actually to everything), kids base their decisions on visual cues. If you hide something inside the tabs there's more than 90% chance the content won't be seen.

Only 2 out of 37 children clicked on tabs when I conducted user testing (age group: 6-9years). They also use thumbnails as the main form of navigation - flashy images and animations draw their attention.

Now imagine: You're asking a 4-year-old to open activities tab. The kid, most likely, can't even read his own name...
Are they gonna miss some crucial information if they won't click on Audio & Activities tabs? Is it relevant information for them and are they gonna enjoy it, or is it just because you want them to click on it?

When it comes to children, you have to imagine yourself in their shoes - is that the content you would consider as fun? Would you share it with your friends? If it is, then don't be afraid of the page length and stop hiding it underneath the tabs. Just switch up the order and look closely to analytics.

If the content is not something the children might enjoy, then I really wish you good luck in tricking them to interact with it. Kids are even more stubborn than adults - they need instant gratification and they rarely use back-button. So if you miss the shot, most likely you will lose that user.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @MikeM is a responsible question to ask: are you allowing research to dictate your design decisions? But for any reason that you wish to encourage more Audio clicks, move the button to the top and left. 
[image]

There is proven research that in Western cultures, people read the left-most and top-most content first. https://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/ and you can use this science to your advantage. Based on this articles research on F-shaped reading, your current placement of the Audio and Activities buttons reside in a dead zone.

Another subjective idea is to change the name of the button, Audio. Since Videos are so popular among visitors now-a-days, Audio has taken a back seat. If you think about it, Videos have audio too. Therefore, a button named Audio seems inferior to a button named Video. IMO, call the Audio button something fun and enticing like "Listen Up" or "Now Hear This"